# Decision Regression Tree Plot Error: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Hi I received error message `x and y must be the same size` when plotting regression decision tree.

The data looks like
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0)

# convert x, y, from dataframe to array
arr = df2.as_matrix(columns=df2.columns[1:11])
arr_y = df2.as_matrix(columns=df2.columns[0:1]).reshape(-1,)

# Fit regression model
regr_1.fit(arr, arr_y)
arr_y_1 = regr_1.predict(arr)

# plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(arr, arr_y, c="k", label="training samples")
plt.plot(arr, arr_y_1, c="g", label="n_estimators=1", linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel("data")
plt.ylabel("target")
plt.title("Decision Tree Regression")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

X, Y are in the shape same as [scikit learn example code](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_adaboost_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-adaboost-regression-py).

> print(arr.shape)

`(97087, 9)`

> print(arr_y.shape)

`(97087,)`

However, I received error message indicates they are not in the same shape

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-ada19fe101c4> in <module>()
      1 plt.figure()
----> 2 plt.scatter(arr, arr_y, c="k", label="training samples")
      3 plt.plot(arr, arr_y_1, c="g", label="n_estimators=1", linewidth=2)
      4 plt.xlabel("data")
      5 plt.ylabel("target")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3468                          vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha,
   3469                          linewidths=linewidths, verts=verts,
-> 3470                          edgecolors=edgecolors, data=data, **kwargs)
   3471     finally:
   3472         ax._hold = washold

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1853                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1854                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1855             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1856 
   1857         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4241         y = np.ma.ravel(y)
   4242         if x.size != y.size:
-> 4243             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
   4244 
   4245         if s is None:

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Comment: They're not the same size - X has 9 columns, and y is one-dimensional. You can only plot one of the input features against y at a time.

Comment: thank you, but the code example here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_adaboost_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-adaboost-regression-py  x.shape is `(100, 1)`  y.shape is `(100,)`  `plt.scatter(X, y, c="k", label="training samples")` shows the plot without issue

Comment: Note: `(100,1)` - still only one dimensional. Your X is `(97087, 9)` - 9 dimensions.